# Where can I get the source code of module __builtin__ in python?

Tags: python

where can I get the source code for module **builtin** in python ? I am interested in version 2.6.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an Ubuntu-specific solution (though this should work on Debian, Mint, and other related distros), download the source and you'll find bltinmodule.c there.

On my Ubuntu system, it is located under my python source directory, i.e., `.../python2.6-2.6.6/Python/bltinmodule.c`

`apt-get source xxx` will download the source for the specified package into a sub-directory of your current directory.

This should do the trick:

```
 apt-get source python2.6  
 view ./python2.6-2.6.6/Python/bltinmodule.c
```

If you don't want to use `find`, rebuild your locate database with `sudo updatedb` and then you can do a `locate bltintmodule.c` to find your file.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the folder you installed the Python libraries in, check under the version\Python folder - you should find the bltinmodule.c file.

Something along the lines of C:\python\2.X\Python

On CentOS it's...

```
root@xenos ~> locate bltinmodule.c
/usr/src/debug/Python-2.5.1/Python/bltinmodule.c
/usr/src/debug/Python-2.6.4/Python/bltinmodule.c
```

Perhaps you need http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/python-dev

Comment: I am on Ubuntu , not windows. Under my /usr/lib/python2.6 I don't see any such file: find . -name '*.c'

Comment: Well, if it's definitely not there... I've not got an Ubuntu system here - updating main answer...

Comment: I did this search with no results: sudo find / -name 'bltinmodule.c'. Anyone else has an answer for Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest place to find the CPython source code is the web view of the Mercurial repository:
http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.6/Python/bltinmodule.c

(Updated link to refer to the copy in Mercurial, although 2.6 security releases happened from the SVN repo)

Comment: For later versions, development has moved to Mercurial. See http://hg.python.org/cpython

Comment: Specifically, [this](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c9910fd022fc/Python/bltinmodule.c) would be the source for the builtin module under Mercurual.