# in eclipse, how can I read python build-in func source code? eg filter, map, reduce

Tags: python, eclipse, macos

how can I read python build-in function's source code? eg, filter, map, reduce

Comment: for python 2.5.2, these appear in `Python-2.5.2/Python/bltinmodule.c`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858701/where-can-i-get-the-source-code-of-module-builtin-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These functions are written in C. You can view the source code [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip) (be sure to select the correct version by [tag](http://hg.python.org/cpython/tags)) or download the source tarball from [here](http://python.org/download/).

Anyway, you can find the code for all function in `__builtin__` in the file `Python/bltinmodule.c`. I.e. the implementation of `filter` is a function called `builtin_filter`.

The sources for other modules are in the `Modules/` folder.

Comment: Looking in the repository is my preferred way to look this up: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip

Comment: @ms4py Thank you for providing the repo URL, I've update my answer